# Icecast - Moving listeners from autodj to live stream without resetting the stream

Tags: icecast

I have Icecast server and I have /autodj.mp3 and another mountpoint called /stream.mp3

When I broadcast Live I am broadcasting to /stream.mp3

But when I'm listening and I start broadcasting Live it does not automatically switch to Live, unless I reload the page with the stream, then it works

Any ideas?

Icecast.xml

```
    <mount>
<mount-name>/autodj.mp3</mount-name>
<stream-name>Niall FM AutoDJ</stream-name>
</mount>
<mount>
<mount-name>/stream.mp3</mount-name>
<fallback-mount>/autodj.mp3</fallback-mount>
<fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
<stream-name>Niall FM</stream-name>
    <public>1</public>
</mount>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of band discussion on IRC with the user revealed that they were streaming Ogg/Vorbis content to `/autodj.mp3` and Icecast consequently refused to move listeners to a MP3 stream logging in at `/stream.mp3`.

Icecast enforces a very high level compatibility, but actually to ensure largest possible listener software compatibility it is highly recommended to closely match all stream and codec parameters between streams that fall back to each other.

Comment: I actually spoke to some guys on the Icecast IRC and managed to fix it. This was precisely the issue. I now stream in Ogg Vorbis both ways.